# Elasticsearch range query with multiple condition

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, java-8

I have to fetch records from Elastic Search on the basis of date it is updated and created. I have these two fields updatedDate and createdDate and the condition should be:

1. To fetch records that has updatedDate within the range of past 3 years.
2. If updatedDate is null, fetch records that has createdDate within the range of past 3 years.

I have written the query in java for fetching the records on the basis of record createdDate:

```
.must(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("createdDate").from(startDate,true).to(endDate,true));
```

startDate and endDate holds the date range.

I am new to Elastic Search, don't know how to implement the above condition.

Comment: Better to share index mapping, sample and expected docs in JSON format so that we can provide working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have not provided any index data, so adding a working example with sample index data, mapping, search query and search result that satisfies all the conditions required for your use case.

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "createdDate": {
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
        "type": "date"
      },
      "updatedDate": {
        "format": "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
        "type": "date"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "createdDate": "2020-08-15T00:00:00Z"  
}
{
    "createdDate": "2019-08-15T00:00:00Z"  
}
{
    "createdDate": "2010-08-15T00:00:00Z"  
}
{
    "updatedDate": "2021-08-15T00:00:00Z",
    "createdDate": "2002-08-15T00:00:00Z"
}
{
    "updatedDate": "2018-08-15T00:00:00Z",
    "createdDate": "2020-09-15T00:00:00Z"
}
{
    "updatedDate": "2000-08-15T00:00:00Z",
    "createdDate": "2020-09-15T00:00:00Z"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": {
                    "range": {
                      "createdDate": {
                        "gte": "now-3y",
                        "lte": "now"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "must_not": {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "updatedDate"
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "range": {
                "updatedDate": {
                  "gte": "now-3y",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64965551",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "createdDate": "2020-08-15T00:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64965551",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "createdDate": "2019-08-15T00:00:00Z"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "64965551",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "updatedDate": "2018-08-15T00:00:00Z",
          "createdDate": "2020-09-15T00:00:00Z"
        }
      }
    ]
```